# How to extract data from MS Planner to Snowflake using Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory, microsoft-planner, microsoft-graph-plannertasks

I would like to extract data from Ms Planner and load it into snowflake. I am using ADF as integration tool. How to achieve this?

Comment: Hi - what have you tried and what specific issues are you facing? Have you set up connections to your source/target and do they error? If so, what’s the error message and how have you configured the connection?

Comment: Hi NIckW, I dont see any direct connector from ADF to connect with Ms Planner. I dont have any idea about the configuration also. Just came here to get the some suggestion. Please help me if you have come across.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally use a REST API call (Web Activity in ADF) to MS Planner. Here is a link to a GET command for Plans, and there are many other commands you can navigate to from this link:

[MS Planner API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/plannerplan-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Once you do an API call, you will get a JSON Output. You should be able to load this JSON to Snowflake and then shred it using various methods detailed in this link:

[JSON Handling in Snowflake](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/script-data-load-transform-json)

The way I picture it in my head in ADF is:

1. Web call to MS Planner
2. Write the Output to a variable (optional, but could be good for organization purposes)
3. Write the JSON variable to Snowflake (single column)
4. Parse JSON (aka Shredding) from Single Column to Individual Columns depending on the JSON structure (arrays, objects, etc)

Cheers!

Comment: Hi Trent Tamura,